# How to set jquery mask ip range to 255.255.255.255?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is how it goes by default

```
  $('.ip_address').mask('ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ', {

            translation:
            {
                'Z': {
                        pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: false
                    }
            }
    });
```

but what I've tried is this:

```
  $('.ip_address').mask('Z', {

            translation:
            {
                'Z': {
                        pattern: /^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))$/, optional: false
                    }
            }
    });
```

the regular is for ip check for range `255.255.255.255`, but the problem is the `\.` regexp doesn't pass, really couldn't find any working example in google, can you give me a hint on how to do it right using jquery mask?

the examples in google relies on `999.999.999.999` ranges, like here https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This jQuery plugin has limited built-in data validation abilities. But you can still use event handlers to perform your own data validation. You can try something like this :

```
$('.ip_address').mask('Z99.Z99.Z99.Z99', {
    translation: {
        'Z': {
            pattern: /[0-2]/,
            optional: true
        },
    },
    onKeyPress: function(val, e, el, options) {
        var match = val.match(/[0-9]+$/);
        if (match) {
            var v = parseInt(match[0]) || 0;
            $(el).val(val.substr(0, match.index) + ((v > 255) ? 255 : v));
        }
    }
});
```